# fitSystemWindows only for one fragment of tabs

Tags: android

I'm working with an app that has 3 tabs in main activity. The 2nd tab's fragment has a NestedScrollView with header that should be fitted to the system window. The rest of the tab's fragment should be normal with toolbar on them. My attempt to achieve this requirement is setting `setFitsSystemWindows(true)` if the current tab is 2nd otherwise set it to `false`. It works on first run (at 1st tab) then go to 2nd tab, but bugs when going back to the 1st tab. Seems setting it to `false` when going back to 1st tab fits my toolbar to system window. [This is the screenshot of the toolbar when going back to 1st tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RS3I.png)

below is my MainActivity xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
            app:title="Our Menu" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <au.com.appetiser.youfoodz.widgets.bottom_navigation.BottomNavigationLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_behavior="au.com.appetiser.youfoodz.view.GenericBottomBehavior">

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:elevation="0dp"/>
    </au.com.appetiser.youfoodz.widgets.bottom_navigation.BottomNavigationLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In the code I set the boolean value to setFitsSystemWindows like this when switching Tabs:

```
  @Override
  public void onTabTransaction(Fragment currentFragment, int i) {
    rootLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(currentFragment instanceof SecondFragment);
  }
```

Comment: post your code ,what you have done so far ? so we can help

Comment: @rajanks thanks man. I've updated the question above :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of trials and errors I finally solved the issue. It's a dirty workaround but got the thing done. I added a `FrameLayout` parent at top of my `CoordinatorLayout`. I set the `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to my `CoordinatorLayout` and `AppBarLayout`. And on `onTabTransaction` I set `AppBarLayout`'s `fitsSystemWindows` to `false` instead of `rootLayout` which my `CoordinatorLayout`.

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:elevation="0dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_search"
                app:title="Our Menu"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <au.com.appetiser.youfoodz.widgets.bottom_navigation.BottomNavigationLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_behavior="au.com.appetiser.youfoodz.view.GenericBottomBehavior">

            <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/navigation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                app:elevation="0dp"/>
        </au.com.appetiser.youfoodz.widgets.bottom_navigation.BottomNavigationLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

java code:

```
  @Override
  public void onTabTransaction(Fragment currentFragment, int i) {
    appBarLayout.setFitsSystemWindows(currentFragment instanceof SecondFragment);
  }
```

output:

[image]